# SQL When does Aggregate functions end?

Tags: sql

I have a query like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1)
       CASE WHEN COUNT(Example_ID) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Exists'
  FROM Example

 WHERE Example_ID IS NULL
;
```

My question is, if I use aggregates, it'll get the data from the whole table but if I used a standard query i.e:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1)
       1 AS 'Exists'
  FROM Example

 WHERE Example_ID > 0
;
```

Would it stop at the first one it finds? Which one has more optimization?

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: You'd better clarify your question. As it is now, it's very vague.

Comment: @Developing-Developer: A side note: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @jarlh The OP had a typo in the question which hid the first line of the SQL.  I just added the new-line so the entire statement (for both queries) would be seen.

Comment: Which dbms is used? (Different products optimize in different ways.)

Comment: Also, the queries are not producing the same result. Chose the one returning the desired output.

Comment: In C# you have .Any() which stops when it finds a valid entree, what I'm trying to ask is, with the none aggregate query above, does it stop when it finds 1 or does it run the whole query?

Comment: I ran it to find that the second query had 63 less logical reads, 1 less Physical read and 80 less read-ahead reads

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that both queries have a `TOP 1` clause to answer performance would really come down to evaluating the query plan.

The data and indexes are going to affect the performance so the answer is highly specific to your dataset at the time of execution.

If `Example_ID` is *mostly* **not null** then the second query might execute quicker as it is *less* likely to hit a null value in the table scan, unless there is an index on `Example_ID`, then if the Index is sorted in *ascending* order, then the first query should complete before the second query.

The fields and expressions in the `SELECT` clause are largely irrelevant to this discussion, though once the result set has been filtered, the query that is closest to the raw form is likely to return quicker.

---

In SQL Performance questions we always advise that an execution plan is provided and we can help explain why that happens and how improve it.